# How to mock a method call on the constructor using easymock?

Tags: java, constructor, easymock

I have a class that receives a factory as an argument that is called inside the constructor. It must be called there because the object should be fully initalized before it can be used. Something like:

```
class MyClass {

  private Foo foo;

  MyClass(FooFactory fooFactory, Bar bar) {
    this.foo = fooFactory.newFoo(bar);
  }
}
```

An instance of Foo cannot be directly passed to the constructor, so consider that this is a restriction of the problem. MyClass cannot be tested using EasyMock, because fooFactory would be a mock that was not initialized in the setUp:

```
private MyClass myClass;

  public void setUp() {
     FooFactory fooFactory = mock(fooFactory);
     Bar bar = new Bar();
     myClass = new MyClass(fooFactory, bar)
  }
```

So when setUp is called, the call for `fooFactory.newFoo(bar)` inside the constructor will fail with an IllegalStateException, because no such expectations were set.

The question is the, how can you mock method calls in the constructor?

Comment: Why can't you set the expectations of fooFactory in the setUp() method?

Comment: Because the constructor will call fooFactory.newFoo(bar) before replay() it's called and an exception will be throw. If you call replay() in setUp, you can't mock anything else in the other tests.

Answer (score 3):

You can `EasyMock.reset(fooFactory)` in `setUp` after `MyClass` is created.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you mean, but this wouldn't work. The problem here is not to reset the mock, but to make it work before calling replay().

Comment: I think what he's saying is that you can replay the mock, call your constructor, and then reset your mock to use it as if you hadn't called replay.  The documentation on reset is not very clear.

Comment: @peninha it works for me. `reset` returns mock state to the same as after it was created. You will record behavior for `fooFactory.newFoo()`, `replay` it, call `MyClass` constructor, `verify` and `reset` making it available for the actual test method.